# A per site meta shouldn't suggest me reading the tour to get the first badge

Tags: bug, badges, per-site-meta, informed-badge

A per-site-meta shouldn't suggest me reading the tour to get my first badge, since there is no tour on per-site-metas and thus no Informed badge. Here is the screenshot for the reference:

[image]

Made at English Language & Usage Meta.